# Hyperlink inside a TextBlock in Windows Phone

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, xaml, windows-phone

I can see that Hyperlink is available inside the TextBlock element, however Visual Studio underlines it as an error, saying "[TextElementCollection_TypeNotSupportedInHost]".

```
<TextBlock>
    Please <Hyperlink NavigateUri="http://example.com/">click here</Hyperlink>, thanks.
</TextBlock>
```

What is the recommended approach for this? Thanks!

Comment: You should use a RichTextBox instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing text and a component. Instead, [here is how to put links](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/Windows-Phone-7-Mango-First-look-at-RichTextBox-control) in the context of a RichTextBox. Default `TextBox` controls do not support hyperlinks.